# Three images centered, side by side, at the middle of the page

Tags: html, image

I'm trying to center 3 images side by side in the middle of the page but I can't seem to do the last part. My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <title>Exercise #1: Problem 5</title>
    <head>
        <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .column {
        float: left;
        width: 33.33%;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    /* Clearfix (clear floats) */
    .row::after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: table;
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    ////some other code not related
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/belchonock/belchonock1802/belchonock180284998/96079443-small-baby-carrots-in-plate-on-white-background.jpg" alt="Carrots" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/cucumber-slice-royalty-free-image-153556336-1562870568.jpg?crop=0.66682xw:1xh;center,top&resize=480:*" alt="Cucumbers" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/organic-background-green-vegetarian-nutrition_1203-5845.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg" alt="Cabbage" style="width:100%">
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>

    </body>
</html>
```

How can I change this to only html and how can I put the images in the middle of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pseudoclass ::after is probably not the best idea to style the whole ".row". I would recommend to contain only "clearfix" attributes in pseudoclass, and the rest style attributes just in ".row" like below.
Also you didn't set attribute "height" for .row, so browser had no idea that you want it in the middle of the page. Attribute "align-items" sets flex items in the middle but perpendicular to flex-direction.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Exercise #1: Problem 5</title>
<head>
    <style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 5px;
}
.row{
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/belchonock/belchonock1802/belchonock180284998/96079443-small-baby-carrots-in-plate-on-white-background.jpg" alt="Carrots" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/cucumber-slice-royalty-free-image-153556336-1562870568.jpg?crop=0.66682xw:1xh;center,top&resize=480:*" alt="Cucumbers" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/organic-background-green-vegetarian-nutrition_1203-5845.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg" alt="Cabbage" style="width:100%">
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this really easily with the help of bootstrap.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src ...>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src ...>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src ...>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

You need to add bootstrap to your HTML:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Note: the version of bootstrap in this example is 3.4.1

Comment: how to i add bootstrap?

Comment: I edited the answer and added a way to add bootstrap

Comment: and leave the same css I wrote or replace with what you wrote?

Comment: you don't need any of your css, because you imported css from bootstrap. Classes "row", "d-flex justify-content-center" and "col-4" are all from bootstrap directly. You can read more about it [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: but now the images are not side by side centered in the middle of the row, how can I fix that?

Comment: the row is stretched through the entire screen. I don't really understand what the problem is.